# MineFactoryReloaded

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I planted a really big tree that only part of it is in the harvester's range but it still harvested the whole tree. So my question is how big of a tree can a harvester harvest outside of its range?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the tree with the name of the tree please. Just saying "A really big tree" is kinda vague.

Comment: I can't upload a screenshot but, I can tell you that it is a Scared Rubber Tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the wood blocks are adjacent, it will destroy all of them. Only one block needs to actually be in the range.

Answer (score 0):

The harvester according to the [FTB Wiki](http://ftbwiki.org/Harvester) can when supplied with either MJ, EU or RF will harvest crops in front of it in a 3x3 square.

Just based off of some inference I would assume you are playing a modpack that has treecapitator installed which according to the [FTB Wiki](http://ftbwiki.org/Treecapitator) that when an axe is used on a vanilla tree, all connected wood blocks and leaf blocks of the same type of tree fall.

Hope I helped you with your question! :)

Comment: Treecapitator is not on my mod pack and I am harvesting a sacred rubber tree sapling with a mfr harvester. So will the harvester harvest the whole tree if it is out of the harvester's range?

Comment: The MFR harvester should be able to harvest a sacred rubber tree in conjunction with treecapitator